# 16.04 Lenovo x230i freeze on hdd activity

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo, freeze

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes at Lenovo x230i laptop, Win10 dualboot. Seems to be the result of any hdd heavy activity and/or lack of RAM. When enough windows are opened (generally like 10+ browser tabs will do the job, or 5 browser tabs + PyCharm etc.), the hdd indicator light up, mouse cursor moves with great lag, system becomes almost irresponsive, although sometimes closing a browser tab will work and things go back to normal. Sometimes it just stops taking commands and in time freezes completely. 
Where do I start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you run out of RAM and your system start paging / swapping. Open a terminal (Ctrl-alt-t) and run `top` to see your system activity, including cpu and memory.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I realized that Ubuntu has such thing as swap space, that I have none, and that I probably need some. I used https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04 to create this swap file, just opened like 30 9gag tabs along with PyCharm and it worked like a charm. I will write if I encounter any further problems, but so far it all seems good. Thanks a bunch again!
PS Can't vote you up, don't have enough rep for that, sorry :(